# AWS SES delivery failed: returning message to sender

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, smtp

I have been facing this issue with sending mail to Gmail and other email hosts. I have my domain name verified and also my email account verified. When I send a test email with any of my email accounts from SES it delivers but when I try to send through my webmail it keeps giving me an error:

```
This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

  *****@gmail.com 
    all hosts for 'gmail.com' have been failing for a long time (and retry time not reached)
Reporting-MTA: DNS; ip-172-31-33-45.ap-south-1.compute.internal

Action: failed
Final-Recipient: rfc822; ****@gmail.com 
Status: 5.0.0
```

Please kindly find the [image]attached screenshot.

[image]

Comment: That error message is coming from a private IP address. What do you have running in a VPC that might be generating that message? What do you mean by "send through my webmail"? Please provide more details.

Comment: What I meant by "send through my webmail" is when I tried to send an email through webmail on my cpanel it won't go through but when I send through SES email it goes through. AM updating my question to add the screenshot to it for you to see.

Comment: When I send to email ending with my domain name e.g ...@mydomain.com, it will go through but if I send to like of ...@gmail, ...@yahoo.com and more it won't

Comment: Is it still in Sandbox mode? Have you verified those other addresses?

Comment: Verification Status: Verified. Like I said when I send an email from the SES Home page it goes through to other email hosts like Gmail, Yahoo and the rest but when I use webmail it doesn't rather it return email with error: "This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:
"